# ActionScript black color value is NaN

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, nan

i'm trying to determine if a color has been supplied as an optional argument to a function.  in order to determine this, i'm simply writing *if(color){...}* and supplying NaN if i don't want there to be a color.

however, it seems that the color black (0x000000) also equates to NaN.  how can i determine if a supplied color number argument is present and black if 0x000000 is passed as the argument?

Comment: Check your assumptions. 0x000000 is 0 is not NaN. To check for NaN you should use isNaN. Also, pay attention: "0x000000" (a string) is not the same as 0x000000 (a hex literal representing 0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some source code would be appropriate.

It sounds like you are saying that the following are equivalent:

```
if ( NaN ) {}
if ( 0x000000 ) {}
```

which is true.  I think you want:

```
if ( isFinite( color ) ) {}
```

Adobe help: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/package.html#isFinite()

Comment: I'm not doubting you, but why is 0x000000 not a number? I thought it would be equal to zero? I searched online and it looks like this is right, but I couldn't find an explanation.

Comment: It is not that 0 == NaN, it is that NaN in an if statement evaluates to false just like 0 does.  NaN has special comparison rules.